# Need to replace my data from json to csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I'm working with json file but I need to replace it with csv file. Do I need to use a library to do that or can I change the jQuery get from json to csv? I've tried that but no luck not working.

My javascript code is th

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'somefile.json',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
   $(".score-text").each(function( index, value ) { 
          value.innerText = data['box'+(index+1)].total;
      });
    
      $(".data").each(function( index, value ) {  
          var boxIndex = Math.floor(index/4);
          width = data['box'+(boxIndex+1)]['bar'+(index+1-boxIndex*4)];
          value.innerText = width;
          value.style.width = width;
      });
  }
 });   
});
```

I'm using csv to array but getting some errors this is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
     url: "somefile.csv",
     success: function (csvd) {
         data = $.csv2Array(csvd);
     },
     dataType: "text",
     complete: function (data) {
         $(".score-text").each(function( index, value ) { 
          console.log(data);
          value.innerText = data['box'+(index+1)].total;
      });
    
      $(".data").each(function( index, value ) {  
          var boxIndex = Math.floor(index/4);
          width = data['box'+(boxIndex+1)]['bar'+(index+1-boxIndex*4)];
          value.innerText = width;
          value.style.width = width;
      });
     }
 });  
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery does not know about CSV files. You would need to request it as `dataType: "text"`, then parse it yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks I'm using csv to array but I'm getting some errors

Comment: "some errors" is not useful diagnostics. Also, if it is at all possible, consider parsing CSV at serverside (and sending as JSON) instead, using a CSV library. Or use something like [papaparse](http://papaparse.com/) to parse data for you; CSV, even if it looks trivial, actually has some nasty corner cases.